# Immutable collection with expiration

Tags: java, guava

**What I'm doing**: I'm gathering a potentially large collection of objects and asking the user for input based on the collection. I want to cache the objects to avoid reacquiring them, but I want the collection to expire after a short time in case the user flakes out. If needed, I'll reacquire the objects. The collection will not change over the short time span involved.

**What I've looked at**: [Guava's Cache](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) looks promising because of the time-based expiration. However, a couple of things bother me about it. I don't really need a map -- the collection will be accessed in its entirety or not at all. And I'm worried that I can run into a race condition where items in the Cache start expiring as I'm accessing the Cache. That adds a level of complexity, having to track if all my items are in the Cache, eliminating some of the value of the cache.

**My Question**: Am I asking for trouble if, instead of placing individual items in the Cache, I make a Guava ImmutableCollection of them and place that into the Cache? It seems that way I access the entire collection in one go, and the collection is either in the cache or it isn't (in which case I rebuild it all). Are there pitfalls with this approach that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not unusual to have a static, singleton key for a Guava cache.  `Cache` provides a lot of benefit even when not used as a `Map`.  I would just do something like this:

```
 private static final Object CACHE_KEY = new Object();

 private LoadingCache<Object, List<SomeType>> cache = 
      CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .softValues()
        .build(valuesLoader());

 //...
 List<SomeType> values = cache.get(CACHE_KEY);
```

In my code base, I use caches with single values in a few places, so I've abstracted this to a `SingleValueLoadingCache<T>` which exposes a no-arg `get()` method and encapsulates the cache and key.

> It seems that way I access the entire collection in one go, and the collection is either in the cache or it isn't (in which case I rebuild it all). Are there pitfalls with this approach that I'm not seeing?

Just in case you haven't found it yet, you probably want a `LoadingCache` by passing a `CacheLoader` to the `build` method of the `CacheBuilder`.  That way you just always call `get()`, and if the value isn't in the cache, it is loaded for you automatically and synchronously, using the `CacheLoader` you've provided.

Comment: Super minor nit, but I'd just use `Object CACHE_KEY = new Object()` to ensure nothing but that constant matches, unlike the empty string which could come from any number of different places.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a `LoadingCache` with a single artificial key, you can use [`Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoizeWithExpiration(com.google.common.base.Supplier,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)), which gives you a slightly simpler API. The downside is that it doesn't expose the knobs and statistics that a `Cache` does.

```
private Supplier<Collection<Foo>> cachingSupplier = 
    Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(valueSupplier,
        5L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use case seems to describe the value as being a collection of objects. So the workflow you describe "make a Guava ImmutableCollection of them and place that into the Cache." Is an appropriate action.